Dynamically expand a 12 col grid
I have 2 rows consisting of 12 cols
and a test button which should expand the first col of first row after each click.
HTML and CSS:
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <!-- 12 times -->
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <!-- 12 times -->
</div>

.row {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 calc((100% / 12);
  position: relative;
  border: 1px dashed darkgray;
  border-right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

This is how I am expanding the column (when clicking the button):
const minColWidthPercentage = (1 / 12) * 100;

expandCol(col) {
  const colStyle = window.getComputedStyle(col);
  const flexBasis = parseFloat(colStyle.flexBasis) + minColWidthPercentage;
  col.style.setProperty("flex", `1 1 calc(${flexBasis}%)`);
}

As soon as I comment out the 'padding: 10px;' from col's css, everything works fine.
The right border of the expanded column correctly aligns with the border of the column below from the second row.
But if I keep the padding, the alignment breaks.
Without padding after expanding 4 times:

With padding after expanding 4 times:

I already tried 1 1 calc(${flexBasis}%+${padding*n}px) approach.
But this does not solve the problem.
I think I should include the padding somehow in the percentage calculation, but how exactly?
PS: Note that, while expanding I am removing the neighbour column in another function.

Please convert your html/css/code to a working snippet.

I added the missing closing tags for col divs

...but still no working code snippet.

box-sizing: border-box; on the cols - also, grid may be easier to achieve this

Thanks, box-sizing: border-box; solved the problem.

you can adjust the flex-basis calculation to include the padding and borders, or use box-sizing to ensure padding and border are included in the width calculation.
.col {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 calc((100% / 12));
  position: relative;
  border: 1px dashed darkgray;
  border-right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

If you prefer to manually calculate the padding and border, you can do so by modifying the expandCol function as follows:
const minColWidthPercentage = (1 / 12) * 100;

expandCol(col) {
  const colStyle = window.getComputedStyle(col);
  const flexBasis = parseFloat(colStyle.flexBasis);

  // Get the padding and border width
  const padding = parseFloat(colStyle.paddingLeft) + parseFloat(colStyle.paddingRight);
  const border = parseFloat(colStyle.borderLeftWidth) + parseFloat(colStyle.borderRightWidth);

  // Calculate new flexBasis including padding and border
  const newFlexBasis = flexBasis + minColWidthPercentage;

  // Set the new flex property
  col.style.setProperty("flex", `1 1 calc(${newFlexBasis}% - ${padding + border}px)`);
}


box-sizing: border-box; solved the problem.
As I mentioned before, subtracting or adding padding and the border as a constant does not solve the problem.
